# Use one popup to show different content based on which button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I want to use the same jquery function and the same popup div in multiple location ( restaurant menu) and call up a different img in the popup. I have the popup working just fine. But no matter what I try the function defaults to the first on the page. What am I doing wrong? pulling me hair out here?

```js
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#A1, #A2").click(function(){
  $("#overlay").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#overlay_div").fadeIn("slow");
 });
 $("#button-close").click(function(){
  $("#overlay").fadeOut("slow");
  $("#overlay_div").fadeOut("slow");
 }); 
});
 
</script>
```

```html
<body>
<div class="button-a"alt=""id="A1">PRESS</div>
 <div id="overlay">
  <div class="overlay_div" id="overlay_div">
         <div class="button-close" id="button-close">X</div>
   <img src="dsc_1064.png"style="margin:5% auto; display: block;" alt="" ></img>
   <h1>Malasadas...... Soo Good</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
   
<div class="button-a"alt=""id="A2">PRESS</div>
 <div id="overlay">
  <div class="overlay_div" id="overlay_div">
      <img src="IMG_5718.jpg"style="margin:5% auto; display: block;" alt="" ></img>
   <h1>Come and Have Some Soup</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements on the same page with the same `id`

Answer (score 0):

Your problems:

- You cannot have duplicated ID's on the same page. The value must be unique within the HTML document.
- There is no `</img>` end tag in HTML.
- For readability, and to simplify production and debugging, try and stick to one type of classname/ID case formatting. Here you have a mixture of `my-classname` (Kebab Case) and `my_classname` (Snake Case). There is also `myClassname` (Camel Case) - choose one style and stick to it.

I'd probably do something similar to this:

**CSS:**

```
.overlay_div { display: none; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="button-a" id="A1">PRESS</div>
<div class="button-b" id="A2">PRESS</div>
```

Notice that I'm only using one overlay but it contains the content for two popups, `overlay_div_a` and `overlay_div_b`..

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div class="overlay_div" id="overlay_div_a">
        <div class="button-close" id="button-close">X</div>
        <img src="dsc_1064.png">
        <h1>Malasadas...... Soo Good</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay_div" id="overlay_div_b">
        <div class="button-close" id="button-close">X</div>
        <img src="dsc_5718.png">
        <h1>Come and Have Some Soup</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#A1, #A2").click(function() {
    // close current overlay content
    $('.overlay_div').hide();
    // get the classname of the button pressed
    var class = $(this).attr('class');
    // show relevant overlay content for button pressed
    switch (class) {
        case "button-a":
            $('#overlay_div_a').show();
            break;
        case "button-b":
            $('#overlay_div_b').show();
            break;
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0sn0zn56/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer and input. Im still confused though. From what Im looking at this would require me to write a div for each button ie: button-a, button-b ect...... I have 40+ items in the <ul> to add this to. Would this not make my stylesheet a bit over sized. Is there not a way to

Comment: P.S. Thanks for the no </img> comment. I have removed them